# Need assistance in verifying that a textbook answer on probability question is wrong (I think so)

Tags: probability

Problem: Given that Z~N(0,1) use the GDC (calculator) to find
the probability:

i. P(|Z|<0.4)

Why is P(|Z|<0.4) around 0.311, according to my textbook's answer key. Shouldn't it be 1 since |Z|<0.4) equals Z<0.4 and Z>-0.4, which, by using the standard normal curve sketch, covers the entire area of the graph. Area is the same as probability for the graph, and thus the probability should be 1. Am I wrong?

Comment: You only have a little error in your thinking. The condition "$Z<0.4$ and $Z>-0.4$" means that BOTH of the conditions need to be true. For example. $Z=-1$ only fulfills the fist one, and $Z=0$ fulfills both of them. $Z=1$ would fulfill only the latter condition. Therefore, the are is indeed the "integral" from $Z=-0.4$ to $Z=0.4$.

Comment: The answer $0.311$ is correct. Usually the values of the integral are tabulated from $-\infty$, and (at least in my book) the tabulated value is $0.6554$. This is the integral from negative infinity to $0.4$. Now to get the integral from $-0.4$ to $+0.4$, I calculate $2\times (0.6554-0.5) = 0.3108$.

Comment: So what don't you understand, precisely? Is it WHY you need to calculate it, or HOW?

Comment: I'm so stupid. Thank you I understand now lol

Comment: I was looking at Z<0.4 and Z>−0.4 by themselves, not realizing both conditions need to be met. What a basic mistake lol